# How to do decimal encoding of DNA sequences (dataset)?

Tags: k-means, hierarchical-clustering, dna-sequence

I need to perform K-means clustering and Hierarchical clustering of DNA sequences(nucleotide) sequences which i have downloaded in FASTA format. So before performing clustering I need to do DECIMAL ENCODING OF bases(a,t,c,g).. so how to do that.. so that i can take this input in the matrix form in MATLAB?.

Comment: Do you have Matlab's bioinformatics toolkit? It can load FASTAs directly.

Comment: Yes sir i have MATLAB bioinformatics toolkit, but for performing kmeans clustering, don't i need numerical data.. for that i need to convert a,c,t,g into decimal values.. how to do that.. or will by directly loading FASTA files i can perform clustering on those fasta files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nt2int function. Documentation on it below:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/nt2int.html